# Perform model pop-up on image which is fetch from database and displaying on the page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Fetching image from database and then displaying on page using `echo` and when i am trying to perform model pop-up but its not working.Here is image which is fetching from database .

```
<?php echo '<img  id="myImg" class="small" src="img/'.$img.'" alt="'.$img.'">'; ?>
```

and here is model code which is i am using

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
<span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>
<img class="modal-content" id="img01">
<div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

and here is j_query

```
<script>
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
span.onclick = function() { 
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

and here is CSS i am using

```
#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}
#myImg
{
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}
.modal-content, #caption { 
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

but this code is not working i don't know what i am doing wrong, and when i am trying to other JavaScript function still it is not working on the image . nothing is working on image except CSS . So help me please .

Comment: Just need a bit more info if you don't mind. `console.log` the `img` var after initializing it. What do you get?

Comment: Wrap your script in a function and then echo the script after you place the image maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Think you're looking for event listeners. They work with dynamic content

```
var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
if(img.length > 0){
  for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
    img[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        // Do stuff here
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: still not working i already uses event listener but it seems nothing is working with this img, nothing is working and i used for other `li` image to make pop -up model it all is working but , this not why i don't know .

Comment: I'm struggling with this same exact issue now. I have custom scripts running for my form elements. When I load elements in to a div dynamically I have to reinitialize the scripts I did at first. My problem is, I'm struggling to detect when the dom has changed. Once I figure it out I'll post that here. will help us both.